# Relia Theme Homepage Articles Excerpt displays the current page excerpt not the posts being pulled

Tags: excerpt

Help! Spent many hours on this: Using Relia Theme, for the Homepage Articles the Excerpt displays the current page excerpt for all three Articles, not the excerpts from the respective Articles (aka "posts").

Comment: did you create the code for the section yourself? in this case, please post the full code here. if not, please contact the theme developer for support.

Comment: @Michael Nothing custom here... I did contact dev and I'm getting nothing. Tnx for responding anyhow.